# What is the best practices to connect to postgresql from microservice

Tags: c#, postgresql, database-administration

I have a multi tenant c# project with 60 microservices connected to multiple postgresql databases. I'm using open/close connection on each transaction. I'm not sure that this is the best practices.
Do I have to open one connection to each database on each microservice and use it on all my activities or open/close on each transaction

Comment: Usually a good practice is to open/close a connection to your DB for each operation you want to perform, 'open/close on each transaction' is the recommendation, imagine if you keep a connection opened for the whole lifecycle of your microservice, depending on the workload it could cause connection starvation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider use Unit of Work pattern plus Dependency Injection practices.

I let you here a Microsoft document explaining the Unit of Work pattern

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

If this approach isn´t valid for you, using **only** ORMs like Dapper or Entity Framework should be another approach, but in this case I strongly recommend you to isolate this in "repositories" entities. This way, everytime you instance and use a repository (using Dependency Injection) you won´t have to deal with transaction details (the connection will be opened every time you instance this entity and closed when you call Dispose method).